# Barplot per month for all countries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data showing temperature and date from different countries.

```
Date  Temperature    Units  Year Month Statistics Country CODE
                                                             
Jan 1991        -26.2  Celsius  1991   Jan    Average  Canada  CAN
Feb 1991        -21.0  Celsius  1991   Feb    Average  Canada  CAN
Mar 1991        -18.2  Celsius  1991   Mar    Average  Canada  CAN
Apr 1991         -8.6  Celsius  1991   Apr    Average  Canada  CAN
May 1991          0.8  Celsius  1991   May    Average  Canada  CAN
```

I want to make a barplot for each month for only the year 1991. I want to create a loop so, in the end, I get 12 plots, each with five different bars(countries) showing the temperature per country in 1991.

I did this:

```
tempcountries.groupby(['Country','Month']).plot.bar(y='Temperature',legend=True)
plt.title("Monthly AVerage Temperature")
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Average Temperature °C')
plt.show()
```

But I get one plot per country and per month and not all countries per month.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
tempcountries.groupby(['Month']).plot.bar(x='Country', y='Temperature',legend=True)
```

If you want these in one figure, the seaborn package provides a nice interface for creating grids of graphs from categorical variables in a pandas DataFrame.

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(tempcountries, col="Month")
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, y="Temperature", x="Country")
```

Answer (score 0):

The package Seaborn can do this easily for you.

```
import seaborn as sns

# Plot all countries for each month
sns.catplot(x = 'Country', y = 'Temperature', col = 'Month', kind = 'bar',
            data = tempcountries[tempcountries['Year'] == 1991]
            )
```